# iOS purchase transaction in valid receipt but not in payment queue

Tags: ios, transactions, payment, receipt

While testing purchases with an Apple sandbox user i somehow generated purchases which are present in the validated receipt but there is no corresponding transaction available in the payment queue.

So here is what i do:

1) On app start i register to the payment queue:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

2) no transactions are report via

```
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

3) when a new payment is added, everything works quite fine and a purchase with the state `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing` pops up in

```
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

4) the the receipt is then sent to the server and successfully validated. But when i look into the parsed json receipt, i'll also get a few other purchases which were not finished back then (because of some debugging tests).

5) Normally these transactions should pop up in the `SKPaymentQueue` when i restart the app and finish. This also works for me now. But there are no corresponding transactions for these few old ones. I only get the recently bought one with the correct state `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`

Even if i do this, there are no transactions finished (because they are not in the queue):

```
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions]) {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

How can i solve this tricky problem?

Comment: Is there maybe a way to get a transaction object from its transaction id?